# Sync CoreData base?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have two iPhones. I need to sync sql base on first one with the second. Is it rigth, If I just copy sqllite file from the Documents folder?

Comment: Unidirectional or bidirectional synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this successfully by just copying the SQLLite DB as you said.